# realtime app need push service advice

Tags: websocket, socket.io, firebase, pusher, pubnub

I am looking for a realtime hosted push/socket service (paid is fine) which will handle many connections/channels from many clients (JS) and server api which can subscribe/publish to those channels from a PHP script.

Here is an example:

The client UI has a fleet of 100 trucks rendered, when a truck is modified its data is pushed to channel (eg. /updates/truck/34) to server (PHP subscriber), DB is updated and receipt/data is sent back to the single truck channel.

We have a prototype working in Firebase.io but we don't need the firebase database, we just need the realtime transmission.  One of the great features of firebase.io is that its light and we can subscribe to many small channels at once.  This helps reduce payload as only that object data that has changed is transmitted.

Correct me if I am wrong but I think pusher and pubnub will allow me to create 100 truck pub/subs (in this example) for each client that opens the site?

Can anyone offer a recommendation?

Comment: How about simply having your client-side code delete the update after it receives confirmation? Or have the truck send an ack-of-ack back to the server, which then deletes the update. Both would keep your Firebase data as small as "the updates that are currently in progress".

Comment: Thanks Frank! This is our recommendation as well when you simply want to send ephemeral data. The client simply "acks" the message by removing it when it sees it.

Comment: Note, however, that in this case, a messaging queue may not be what you want. If you're tracking the location of vehicles, why not just overwrite the position each time it's updated. Then you'll never have stale messages on Firebase -- just whatever the last position was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I work for Firebase]

Firebase should continue to work well for you even if you don't need the persistence features. We're not aware of any case where our persistence actually makes things harder, and in many cases it actually makes your life a lot easier. For example, you probably want to be able to ask "what is the current position of a truck" without needing to wait for the next time an update is sent.

If you've encountered a situation where persistence is actually a negative for you, we'd love to hear about it. That certainly isn't our intention.

Also - we're not Firebase.io -- we're just Firebase (though we do own the firebase.io domain name).

Comment: Thanks for commenting Andrew.  One thing that we are struggling with Firebase (which may be our lack of understanding) is the extra layer of data that we must keep in sync with our db table.  For instance if the mssql table has been updated directly/or through a 3rd party feed then it will be out of sync with firebase and all realtime clients.  However if the clients used a channel direct to the db server to get the table contents then we don't have to manage that 2nd data source.  And we also get query power back, which firebase is currenlty limited.

Comment: There's 2 good solutions to this: (1) Simply have all write operations go directly to your servers using AJAX, and then broadcast changes out from your server using our REST API (2) Use a Node.js client on your server, so that you get notified of changes as they occur and you can update your database. 
Since it sounds like you're using PHP, option #1 is probably the way to go. There's a wrapper for PHP here that someone wrote to make the REST calls easier from PHP (note that this is a 3rd party project -- not official): https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

Comment: I have been testing your idea (1) Andrew and I think that will work well for us.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that you can use [Pusher](http://pusher.com) to achieve this - *I work for Pusher*.

PubNub previously counted each channel as a connection, but they now seem to have introduced multiplexing. [This FAQ](https://help.pubnub.com/entries/21882797-How-Many-Channels-does-Multiplexing-Support-) states you can support 100 channels over the multiplexed connection.

So, both of these services will be able to achieve what you are looking for. There will also be more options available via this [Realtime Web Tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) which I maintain.

Comment: thanks leggetter, do you know as its not clearly stated on pushers website, if I can use php to  subscribe to a channel so I can update DB.  I understand i could use a node app to bridge the php script, but i was looking for a direct link to php.  Pubnub seem to be the only one to have this sorted.

Comment: Yes, PubNub has this. There is also a work-in-progress one available for Pusher called [WrenchPusher](https://github.com/westinpigott/WrenchPusher). Do you plan to run the PHP script as a daemon process? If you don't plan to run the PHP 'subscriber' as a daemon then you could get the trucks to make HTTP requests to an endpoint when their status changes (events), update the database and publish the changes through your realtime service provider. This all depends on how how accurate you want your geo-positioning to be (a guess) - very accurate: then a persistent connection is obviously better.

Comment: All what @leggetter said is true. Just want to add that [PubNub has a new feature called BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/). This means that you do not have to subscribe from your server (which can be difficult for you to scale and do properly across multiple servers). BLOCKS lets you make custom REST calls (using Node.js/Promises) to your server or other 3rd party services from within the PubNub Network with each published message in a highly scalable, reliable way.